# Route.js multiple route files and unable to use additional function in the router get/post function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I've managed to breakdown Route.js to multiple controllers but I'm missing the knowledge of why I can't use an additional function to block permissions to view the page.

```
    // route.js
    module.exports = function(app, passport) {

        app.use('/profile', require('./controllers/profileController'));

    }
```

.

```
    // profileController.js
    var express     = require('express')
        , router      = express.Router()
        , permissions = require('../utils/permissions.js')

    // =====================================
    // /profile
    // =====================================
    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('Profile/index.ejs', {});
    }

    module.exports = router;
```

Why can't I do this instead at the profileController?

```
    router.get('/', permissions.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        res.render('Profile/index.ejs', {});
    }
```

It throws the error:

```
    Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
            at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:171:15
            at Array.forEach (native)
            at Route.(anonymous function) [as get] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:167:15)
            at Function.proto.(anonymous function) [as get] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:380:19)
            at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/controllers/profileController.js:10:10)
            at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
            at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
            at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
            at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
            at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
            at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
```

Additional information:

```
    // permissions.js
    var helpers  = require('./helpers.js');

    // route middleware to make sure a user is logged in
    function isLoggedInAJAX(req, res, next) {

        // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on 
        if (req.isAuthenticated())
            return next();

        res.json(helpers.shootMessage(helpers.getNOK(), "You're not logged in!"));
    }

    // route middleware to make sure a user is logged in
    function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

        // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on 
        if (req.isAuthenticated())
            return next();

        //save the page
        req.session.returnTo = req.path;

        // if they aren't redirect them to the home page
        //res.redirect('/info');
        res.redirect('/auth/facebook');
    }
```

Comment: can you post your whole permissions.js file?

Comment: Sure, new edit in a min. Done.

Comment: check my answer :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not exporting your functions in your permissions.js

```
// permissions.js
var helpers  = require('./helpers.js');

// route middleware to make sure a user is logged in
function isLoggedInAJAX(req, res, next) {

    // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on 
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    res.json(helpers.shootMessage(helpers.getNOK(), "You're not logged in!"));
}

// route middleware to make sure a user is logged in
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

    // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on 
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    //save the page
    req.session.returnTo = req.path;

    // if they aren't redirect them to the home page
    //res.redirect('/info');
    res.redirect('/auth/facebook');
}

module.exports = {
     isLoggedInAJAX : isLoggedInAJAX,
     isLoggedIn : isLoggedIn
   }
```

Comment: Thank you! As an additional question: The only reason I need to export it is because its a callback function, right? I didnt need to do this when both those functions were on profileController.js.

Comment: No, you need to export them because they are in a different file :P

Comment: Was about to edit my question to answer it my self, you're absolutely right. Thank you for the help :)